# How to determine the type of value of a column in a DataRow?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following method: `public static void Post(this DataRow dr, string tableName, SqlConnection conn)`

I'm trying to build an `INSERT` statement for my `DataRow`, but I'm running into difficulty trying to determine the type of data each column is in order to format the SQL statement correctly.

I have this:

```
public static void Post(this DataRow dr, string tableName, SqlConnection conn)
{
    string sql = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES(";

    for (int i = 0; i < dr.ItemArray.Length; i++)
    {
        sql += "'" + dr[i].ToString() + "'";

        if (i != dr.ItemArray.Length - 1)
            sql += ",";
    }
}
```

But there are numerous Date and Numeric columns in the table, so obviously not all of my values can be enclosed in `'`.

I know that starting from a `DataTable`, you can do something like this: `myDt.Columns[0].Datatype` which I could then use to branch the logic out and format the values accordingly but I cannot seem to find how to access this information when given just a `DataRow`.

Worst case scenario, I *can* refactor the application to simply take a `DataTable` instead of an individual `DataRow`, but this would require significant work so I'd much prefer to find a way to do it as is.

If it matters, this is a winforms application / .NET 4.5

Comment: why not create parameters?

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Build a `SqlCommand` object, and for each item in your datarow, do something like: `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramNameHere", dataRowValueHere);` at least your query will be parameterized and safe from sql injection.

Comment: If your `DataRow` actually was added to the rows of some DataTable somewhere outside your method - then you can access it using `DataRow.Table` property. Otherwise you can use `dr[i].GetType()` and check is it DateTime or numeric.

Comment: Ah, I misinterpreted what you meant @Ric. I thought you meant adding a list of parameters to the method that define the datatypes. I know to parameterize my queries, I just didn't yet as this was more just a "template" to get the logic down.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Thanks! I was actually unaware this property existed on the `DataRow`. If you'd like to re-submit that comment as a solution, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: @sab669 - to be fair my comment was extremely vague!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `DataRow` actually was added to the rows of some `DataTable` somewhere outside your method - then you can access it using [DataRow.Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.table(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Otherwise you can use `dr[i].GetType()` and check is it DateTime or numeric.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you could just simply call `GetType()` like that; I was trying to find a `Columns` collection belonging to the `DataRow` in a similar manner to how I was with the `DataTable` object :( Thanks again.

Comment: A further step to this could be to remove the `tableName` parameter from the method itself as you could use `DataRow.Table.TableName`

Comment: @Ric While your suggestion can be useful, technically `DataRow` can be created but not added into any `DataTable` rows collection. In this case `.Table` will obviously be null. And we doesn't know exactly what happening in the remaining OP's code - is it "standalone" `DataRow` or not.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev - agreed. It was more of an addition if the row was part of a table and not just a standalone as you put it :)

Comment: In my particular case, the row is part of a `DataTable` that gets built from the database so I can remove the tablename parameter as @Ric suggested. Basically, it pulls rows from a table, processes and modifies the data, sorts it into good / bad rows and updates the table

Answer (score 1):

The best OO Type-Safe way to answer this, I believe, is that you shouldn't be passing direct SQL to be executed.  Create a POCO with actual C# Types that represents your table.

```
T Insert<T>(T classToBeInserted) //where T matches a table

T Select<T>(T classForClauses) //where T matches a table
```

If your generic T matches the table name, and the fields in the class match the column names/types in your table, you can paramaterize and genericize all of your information.

So, if you have a table `Person` with columns `Name varchar(wutev)` and `Age INTEGER`, you should create this class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}
}
```

Then your SQL class could look like this:

```
public class MyPersonalORM
{
    private string _connectionString;

    public MyPersonalORM(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public T Insert<T>(T insertPlz)
    {
        string tableName = typeof(T).Name;
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = ...; // Use reflection to get the properties of T, then reflect into insertPlz to find the values.

        SqlParameter ... // Add each value in the dictionary to a parameter collection.

        // Do a typical Insert, but using Parameters.
    }

    public T Select<T>(T classForClauses)
    {
        string tableName = typeof(T).Name;
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = ...; // Use reflection to get the properties of T, then reflect into insertPlz to find the values.

        SqlParameter ... // Add each value in the dictionary to a parameter collection.

        // Do a typical ADO Selct, but using Parameters for the clauses.
    }
}
```

You have reflection at your fingertips.  It's up to the consumer of the ORM to create classes that map to the database types.

Why?  Cuz that's how E.F. does it.  It never asks the database what types it is.  E.F. requires that you properly map your resources using C# types.

**Of course the real answer** is: Don't use ADO.  Use E.F.  :)

Comment: To be completely honest with you, I'm converting a legacy C++ application to C# .NET. It is literally 30,000 lines of hardcoded data validation on various tables with anywhere from 100 to 315 columns. I lack the time, resources, and probably the skillset to give this application what it *really* needs and it's a pretty unimportant project. The single person in the company who will be using it doesn't care and the only reason I'm even touching this code is so they can scrap the Win2000 machine it runs on.

Comment: If you're super bored, implement it the generic way anyway... for everything.  Then tear out the guts of the existing methods, and put in switches on `string tableName`.  Transform the `DataRow` that is passed in into a POCO, and consume the new generic methods... then take the generic return and transform it back into crap ADO objects to pass back.  lol LoL LAWL.  =-D